# Optional chaining of methods like sort, limit, skip

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, filtering

I'm passing the query params and there could be any combination of `sort`, `limit` or `skip` for the Mongoose Query.

What I've thought of is to create mutliple mongoose queries based on what params have been passed. So if only `sort` is passed then the resulting query will have `Document.find({}).sort({})` and incase only `limit` is passed then query would be `Document.find({}).limit({})`

Should I write something like this -

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(req.query.sortByPrice) {
        Property.find({})
        .sort({ price: req.query.sortByPrice === 'asc' ? 1 : -1 })
        .populate('user_id', 'name')
        .exec((err, properties) => {
            if (err)
                return res
                    .status(404)
                    .json({ error: "Can't get user details!" });
            res.status(200).json(properties);
        });
    }
    if(req.query.limit) {
        Property.find({})
        .limit(req.query.limit)
        .populate('user_id', 'name')
        .exec((err, properties) => {
            if (err)
                return res
                    .status(404)
                    .json({ error: "Can't get user details!" });
            res.status(200).json(properties);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a variable `options` from your request body and pass it as the third argument to the `.find()` query, no need to write redundant code with `if-else` block.

Secnd argument to `.find()` query is `projection`, so don't forget to pass an empty object there.

Try this :

```
let options={};
if(req.query.sortByPrice){
    options.sort = {
        price: req.query.sortByPrice === 'asc' ? 1 : -1 
    }
}
if(req.query.limit){
    options.limit = req.query.limit
}

Property.find({},{},options)
    .populate('user_id', 'name')
    .exec((err, properties) => {
        if (err)
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ error: "Can't get user details!" });
        res.status(200).json(properties);
        return;
    });
```

Note: Dont forget to return after `res.status().json()`, otherwise you might get error `cant set headers after they are sent` . if you try to send response again.

Comment: The solution worked but I had to change the `req.params` to `req.query`. Kindly update your anwser as well.

Comment: okay, updated, and i am glad i could help out. Kindly mark it as accepted answer and upvote as well, it will help others with same/similar issue, and it motivates me to help as well